# Why am I submitting the form twice? jQuery submit() with radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, double-submit-problem

I'm using jQuery to submit a form in an MVC app. I have a breakpoint inside the controller and I see it is being hit twice.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my jQuery

```
 (function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(':radio').change(function () {

            $('#frmMDR').submit();
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

and here is the form html

```
<form action="/Module/ModuleIndex" id="frmMDR" method="get">
  <input id="rdoMaintenance" name="module" type="radio" value="Maintenance" /><label for="rdoMaintenance">M</label>
   <input id="rdoDiagnostics" name="module" type="radio" value="Diagnostics" /><label for="rdoDiagnostics">D</label>
   <input id="rdoRepair" name="module" type="radio" value="Repair" /><label for="rdoRepair">R</label>
 <input id="hdnVehicle" name="hdnVehicle" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
```

I'm guessing I shouldn't be using the change event. If anyone knows how to correct the problem, I'd love to hear any ideas.  Thanks so much for any tips.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: One probable reason could be the event handler being attached twice. Try `$(":radio").data('events').change.length` in the browser console(Firebug). If it return 2, you have 2 change handlers attached.

Comment: aside: `$(':radio')` will attach the event handler to all radio buttons(if there are any) on the page. I prefer `$('#frmMDR :radio').change(function () {`  or `$(':radio','#frmMDR').change(function () {`.

Comment: yes this is absolutely the problem. How do I resolve it? Why am I wiring the handler twice? Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using this... It works ok but seems a bit hacky. I'm all ears for a better solution... 
            $('#frmMDR :radio').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
                $('#frmMDR').submit();
            });

Comment: Maybe if you print out the original click handler, it will give you a clue where it came from.

Comment: is this all the JS code that has something to do with the form inputs?
this code seems to execute just once with me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting two hits because two radio buttons are changing state. Radio buttons only allow one element in a group to be selected so when you are clicking a radio button, two events are happening:

1. A new radio button is selected
2. The previously selected radio button is deselected

This is two events and the reason why your code is being hit twice. To solve it you could give your radio buttons a class and then handle the event on click using the class as the selector.

```
<input class="radio" id="rdoMaintenance" name="module" type="radio" value="Maintenance" /><label for="rdoMaintenance">M</label>
<input class="radio" id="rdoDiagnostics" name="module" type="radio" value="Diagnostics" /><label for="rdoDiagnostics">D</label>
<input class="radio" id="rdoRepair" name="module" type="radio" value="Repair" /><label for="rdoRepair">R</label>
```

And your jQuery could be:

```
$('.radio').click(function () {
    $('#frmMDR').submit();
});
```

Comment: That will only fire on click though - anyone who tabs to the radio control won't have it submit.  Perhaps change it so it fires on selection instead?

Comment: Pretty sure `click` doesn't actually mean "click" for radio buttons. For checkboxes at least, it fires on tab+spacebar.

Comment: I have mocked up some code and tested in IE7/IE8/FF3.6 and Chrome and it works on click and selection through other methods. http://jsfiddle.net/W2yBm/

Answer (score 3):

You should probably just check for selected within the change function for which is selected.  This way it'll only fire for the selected radio button, and you don't need to worry about binding or unbinding any events, and it should work regardless of what input method changed it.

Here's an article on [handling events from check boxes and radio buttons in JQuery](http://www.techiegyan.com/2008/07/09/using-jquery-check-boxes-and-radio-buttons/).

Comment: +1 for thinking of people who don't (or can't) use a mouse, even if it does happen to work in this case. :)